# Struggling with a 12 V reversing motor

Tags: switches, relay, reverse-polarity

I’m struggling with wiring a reversing DC tailgate window motor in my jeep. It’s a circuit with two relays and two switches. I was able to wire the first switch without issues but wiring a second switch in the circuit is blowing the fuse. Any pointers would be great.
diagram here: https://www.fsjnetwork.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13549&start=60

Comment: Part numbers? Wire/schematic drawings?  Can't really help without those.

Comment: the diagram is called serehill tailgate relay diagram. i can try to post it here

Comment: https://www.fsjnetwork.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13549&start=60

Comment: Please edit and add the information to the post, not as comments.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit should give you the behavior you're looking for (updated):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBCswi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the default state with no buttons pressed, both sides of the motor are grounded and nothing happens.
If you push the SW1 Up or SW2 Up, then the left relay activates and connects +12V to the left side of the motor, and it runs in one direction.
If you push SW1 Down or SW2 Down, then the right relay activates and connects 12V to the right side of the motor, and it runs in the other direction.
If you press both an Up and a Down button together, then both relays activate and both sides of the motor are connected to +12V - and nothing happens.

So there's no set of button-presses which will result in a blown fuse.

Comment: i should mention that both switches need to control the motor in both directions. the motor can go up and down so each switch needs to be able to do that

Comment: Ok - I'll make an update ...

Comment: And the buttons could be SPDT center-off rocker or toggle switches.

Comment: the motor is a polarity switching motor so it needs both negative and positive and those polarities need to be reversed to turn the other way. I think i have it wired like you showed but when i use the rear switch i am getting blown fuses so i messed something up

Comment: ok I did a bunch more testing and i found that when i splice my coil trigger on relay pin 86 it causes my blown fuses. hooking one switch up works fine but in the diagram the splice from the coil trigger to my two switches does not work. im sure i misinterpreted the diagram or messed up the wiring. any advice?

Comment: If hooking one of the switches up to the relay causes a blown fuse, then your switches are not wired up as I've drawn them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the appropriate schematic.

[image]